# How do I factory reset my Google Home?

Tags: google-home

I want to clear all of the current settings,configurations and data on my Google Home device and return it back to the original out of the box (factory default) state. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 10):

From the [Factory Data Reset (FDR) Google Home](https://support.google.com/googlehome/answer/7073477?hl=en) docs page:

> Press and hold the microphone mute on the back of Google Home for
>   about 15 seconds. You will hear your Google Assistant confirm that it
>   is resetting Google Home.